# Changing the font size on PoDoFo::PdfFont

Tags: c++, podofo

I'm trying to create a searchable PDF from images that have been OCRed and in PoDoFo 0.9.22  I was able to do it with the code below. I would increase/decrease the font size till I had the correct size that matched my image. But as of 0.10.x (I'm trying to use 0.10.3) there is no `GetFontSize` anywhere and `PdfFont` does not have `SetFontSize`. How can I achieve the same thing in the new version?

Thanks

```
void PrintTextOnPage(PoDoFo::PdfPainter& mPainter, PoDoFo::PdfFont* pFont, const TRectD& pageBB, const PoDoFo::PdfString aText, const TRectD& txtBB)
{
    const PoDoFo::PdfFontMetrics* fontMetrics = pFont->GetFontMetrics();
    float fontSize = pFont->GetFontSize();
    double tmpW = fontMetrics->StringWidth(aText);

    while (tmpW < txtBB.Width)
    {
        fontSize += 1.0;
        pFont->SetFontSize(fontSize);
        tmpW = fontMetrics->StringWidth(aText);
    }
    while (tmpW > txtBB.Width)
    {
        fontSize -= 0.5;
        pFont->SetFontSize(fontSize);
        tmpW = fontMetrics->StringWidth(aText);
    }
    mPainter.DrawText(txtBB.Left, (pageBB.Height) - (txtBB.Top + txtBB.Height), aText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
float fontSize = pFont->GetFontSize();
```

and

```
pFont->SetFontSize(fontSize);
```

with

```
double fontSize = mPainter.GetFontSize();
```

and

```
mPainter.SetFont(pFont, fontSize);
```

Finding the text `GetFontSize` in the sources was easy.

Comment: I'm not sure which version you are looking at but in my source code the only class that has the function `GetFontSize` is `PdfTextStateWrapper`. Also `SetFont` function of `PdfPainter` is private and not accessible.

Comment: You talked about 0.10.x, [GetFontSize()](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/0.10.x/src/podofo/main/PdfPainter.h#L154). [SetFont()](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/0.10.x/src/podofo/main/PdfPainter.h#L128) is public.